# How to disable/disconnect LAN cable during startup

Tags: networking, startup, lan

How to keep my LAN (Ethernet) connection disabled during startup..

Coz when I login to system it  is automatically enabled i dont want that due to some security reason.

Want howto in both ubuntu 10.04 and ubuntu11.10

Regards,
Deena

Answer (score 2):

That's how it works in 11.10 and it should work similar in 10.04:

Edit Network Connections:

[image: open]

Choose your LAN connection:

[image: choose]

Uncheck *Connect automatically*:

[image: disable]